# Binding a Grid with an Object

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have a Grid.
I am binding an object to it.

It has a string and a List as mentioned below:

Mapping:

```
 pubilc string A;
 List<Fields> lst;
```

Field is another class with two fields:

Fields:

```
 pubilc string field1;
     pubilc string field1;
```

When I bind the datasource to this Grid with this object "Mapping", it doesn't show up the field1 and field2 in the other band.

```
 BindingList<Mapping> _conditionList = new BindingList<Mapping>();
 _conditionList.Add(new Mapping());
 grid1.DataSource = _conditionList;
 grid1.DataBind();
 Mapping ds = new Mapping();
 grid1.DataSource = ds;
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: show your code, so that we may tell what are you missing.

Comment: How did you bind he data to the "Fields" instance?

Comment: i bound the whole mapping object which has a List of Fields object

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your grid does not know how to bind to a `Mapping` Object natively. It does know how to bind to a List, though. try the following:

```
grid1.DataSource = ds.lst;
grid1.Databind(); //Only do this if you are not using the "NeedDataSource()" event for binding.
```

Edit: you'll have to make your `lst` public though. C# assumes that objects without an access modifier are private by default, which will break your code in this case.

Comment: In this case its binding only the Fields Object. I want it to bind the whole Mapping object(with Fields object also in the second band)

Comment: If you bind a list of objects, it will use the fields in the object as column names. Also, what exactly should it do with the string a? how should it bind that?